# my css file is in different folder and image in different but root folder is same

Tags: html, css, angular

My css is in *src\app\category-nav\category-nav.component.css* and my image is in *src\assets\images\catbg.jpg* But when i try to link the background image:
below is property i used to set background image:

`background-image: url('..\images\catbg.jpg');`

> ERROR in ./src/app/category-nav/category-nav.component.css Module
> Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js): (Emitted
> value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
> D:\git\noque-subscr\src\app\category-nav\category-nav.component.css:124:26:
> Can't resolve '../images/catbg.jpg' in
> 'D:\git\noque-subscr\src\app\category-nav'

it does not load in browser and gives path error in console.
i tried setting background in common css file also src\assets\css\style.css:
Can anyone please help me where i am wrong?

Comment: maybe you can set it to Absolute path?

Comment: you need improve your question by providing error messages for different environments

Answer (score 1):

if your image is in

```
src\assets\images\catbg.jpg
```

and your css in

```
src\app\category-nav\category-nav.component.css
```

your link should look like this

```
background-image: url("../../assets/images/catbg.jpg")
```

or

```
background-image: url("..\\..\\assets\\images\\catbg.jpg")
```

the `..` tells to go up one directory so `../../` goes to second directory in your path, which is your `src`. from there use the correct path to resolve your image.

Comment: background-image: url("..\\..\\assets\\images\\catbg.jpg");
 i removed first level of directory from path  from the solution you gave then it worked thanks

Comment: oh sorry my bad. there was an extra '../'. updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this not sure but i think it's work.

```
background-image: url('..\assets\images\catbg.jpg');
```

Comment: thanks i got the answer 
but small modifiations
 background-image: url('..\..\assets\images\catbg.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

Where you index.html lies is your root folder. So you can try

```
background-image: url('/assets/images/catbg.jpg'); or 

background-image: url('assets/images/catbg.jpg');
```

starts from root and give the path :)

Comment: with the slash  background-image: url('/assets/images/catbg.jpg');
it wont work when i upload on server

Comment: what do you mean when upload on server? I think if it is a problem with base <base href="./"> in index html?

Comment: i gave same kind of path for some other image when i upload code  on server that image was not loading but on localhost it was working fine

Comment: If you can show the error on server, I can point out what is missing, without the error can't do man. or you can give us the hosted url :) or just open the console check the path it referring to ?